# Web Scraping in HTML to using py-script

Tags: python, html, ssl, web-scraping, pyscript

```
<body class="white-vertion black-bg">
    <!-- Start Loader -->
    <p>
        <py-script>
            import ssl
            from urllib.request import urlopen
            from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

            context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
            result = urlopen("https://blog.naver.com/PostList.naver?blogId=woong3164&categoryNo=0&from=postList", context=context)
            bsObj = BeautifulSoup(result.read(), "html.parser")
        </py-script>
    </p>
```

I used py-script in HTML to do web scraping. However, this error occurred.

```
'JsException(PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1348, in do_open
  h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
 File "/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1282, in request
  self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
 File "/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
  self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
 File "/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
  self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
 File "/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1037, in _send_output
  self.send(msg)
 File "/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 975, in send
  self.connect()
 File "/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1447, in connect
  super().connect()
 File "/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 941, in connect
  self.sock = self._create_connection(
 File "/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 845, in create_connection
  raise err
 File "/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 833, in create_connection
  sock.connect(sa)
BlockingIOError: [Errno 26] Operation in progress

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 429, in eval_code
  .run(globals, locals)
 File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 300, in run
  coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals)
 File "", line 6, in
 File "/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 216, in urlopen
  return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
 File "/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 519, in open
  response = self._open(req, data)
 File "/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 536, in _open
  result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
 File "/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
 File "/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1391, in https_open
  return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
 File "/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1351, in do_open
  raise URLError(err) urllib.error.URLError: )'
```

I think this error was caused by ssl.
How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by using unsupported Python packages. The package **urllib** uses APIs (TCP Sockets) that do not exist in the browser. This is not a limitation of PyScript, no browser application can use socket-based APIs.

The solution is to use supported APIs such as fetch or pyfetch.