# I am unable to install netmiko in pyscript

Tags: netmiko, pyscript

I have already installed netmiko in my pc, but it doesnt run in pyscript.
The error I get is
Loading runtime...
Runtime created...
Initializing components

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Educative PyScript Answers</title>
  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
        <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>

        <py-env>
            - matplotlib
            - netmiko
        </py-env>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Plotting a graph </h1>
        <div id="lineplot"> </div> 
   
        <py-script>  
            import netmiko
            
            print('hello world')
          
        </py-script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "I have already installed netmiko in my pc, but it doesnt run in pyscript." That statement reflects you aren't following how pyscript works. Your system's programs and environments aren't accessible from inside your browser where pyscript is working via web assembly. I suggest looking into how it works more. Netmiko is a networking package. I doubt it works with pyscript. Although it's for different package & use, I suspect the underlying reasoning is similar to the gist of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73150506/8508004), & that due to limitations pyscript won't work as you intend.

Comment: Please review the other PyScript questions. Notice how we need the warnings and errors from the web browser debugger Console and Network tabs. Put those details in your question. Browser applications run in a **sandbox**. Your PC has nothing to do with a PyScript application.